# YII Rights, Best Practice / Mechanism

Tags: php, yii, hierarchy, rbac, rights

I am using YII for a small retail business application. There is a hierarchy of permissions in the organization and I want to mimic that in my application. Does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions about implementing RBAC or Rights for this type of structure ?

Looking for some thoughts as perhaps there is a better way to leverage YII rather than coding this section myself.

Example Hierarchy:
Stores - > Districts - > Regions - > Company.

Does anyone have any thoughts on using existing YII modules to implement this ? Or do you think it better to write custom module to filter the data available to the user based on permissions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You tried to use Yii Users with Yii Rights? here nice tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/423/installing-yii-users-and-rights-to-newly-created-yii-app/

Comment: I suggest you try with this Yii extension called 'cruge', using all of RBAC Yii features. Also you can use complex business rules http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/36467-cruge-module/page__p__175572__hl__cruge